# Angular material select - problem with displaying selected value

Tags: angular, select, angular-material

Im using angular material select:
https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples

And in my app Im using a lot of select inputs and they all have shared option array between all of them. Example array of options:

```
  foods: Food[] = [
{value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
{value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
{value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}];
```

And my problem is: when I select any value and then I reset my option array for example with button click, then selected value dissapears from all select inputs.

**Is there any way to keep the selected value visible on select input when I reset select option array or when I put explicitly new values into option array?**

**Edited:**

To be more clear, lets consider this code:

TS file:

```
foods: Food[] = [
{value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
{value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
{value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}];

selected = 'pizza-1';

resetOptions() {
    this.foods = [];
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <mat-select name="food" [(value)]="selected">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{food.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<p>{{selected}}</p>

<button (click)="resetOptions()">Reset Options</button>
```

And when I select value, the 'selected' propety corectly updates value and this value appears on select input, **but when I click 'Reset Options' button, 'selected' propety still keeps its value, but that value disappears from select input.**

Comment: can you a bit more clear about scenario..

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <mat-select name="food" [(value)]="selected">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{food.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS

```
selected = 'pizza-1';

foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
];
```

Try above code snippet, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

Comment: My problem is different. I can see 'selected' value in TS class, but it disappears in html template.

please consider this method and invoke it after you've selected value:

  reset() {
    this.foods = [];
    console.log(this.selected);
  }

this.selected will have value but select input don't keep this value in html.

Comment: I think you also have to empty your selected variable, please add this code this.selected = '' in your resetOptions method. Thanks